# My mail got sent to the spam folder...what's wrong with my headers?

Tags: php, email, outlook, http-headers

I'm using PHP mail and I have the following headers:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit
X-Mailer: Pressflow
Errors-To: some@email.com
Return-Path: some@email.com
Sender: some@email.com
From: Some Email <some@email.com>
X-SMTPAPI: {"category":"key:some_key"}
```

Where some@email.com is a legitimate email, but I wouldn't disclose it here...

Is there a way to modify this header such that my mail wouldn't get sent to the spam folder in Outlook?

Comment: What makes you think your headers triggered the spam filter's actions?

Comment: Is `some@email.com` the same domain as the server that's actually sending the message? That can get you into trouble sometimes.

Comment: Spammers would just love `X-Spam: I-am-a-meat-popsicle` to let them fill your inbox with impunity.

Comment: SPF can help in some cases. In addition to that, just don't send spam and you should be okay. Note that if it's a major problem and people want to opt-in, then they should whitelist your from address or some other custom header that you make up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKIM). For an easier alternative, try email delivery services such as [Mad Mimi](http://madmimi.com/) or [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

No, otherwise spam filer would be useless

Comment: It's more likely to be the content that's getting filtered than the headers

Comment: but then the contents are normal contents and is nothing spammy....(though I can't post them here due to privacy reasons)

Comment: my answer means: you can't do something on your own (except few things) to force email to not be sent in spam

Answer (score 0):

Headers aren't the only things checked by spam filters. They also check the body, otherwise, they would be pretty useless.

There are plenty of tools and articles available which will help you narrow down why your mail looks like spam.

For issues with the body text, you can use an online tool like [this one](http://www.contactology.com/check_mqs.php)

Also this has been asked **so** many times before, a simple search of `php mail spam` would have given you [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2800898/840973), which has not only helpful information, but a load of related questions in the comments.